# Connecting multiple devices through RAPI2

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, rapi

The Microsoft [RAPI2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920150.aspx) is designed with the ability to talk to multiple devices. But, ActiveSync 4.5.0 allows only allows one device at a time to connect and only allows it over a USB connection.

Is there a way to write a client-server piece for the desktop and mobile device that will allow more than one device to connect to the desktop through a RAPI2 connection? Preferably some way to put RAPI2 over TCP/IP.

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee497070.aspx) they wrote this:

> For Windows CE 5.0 and earlier, this enumeration sequence will only contain a single connected device.

Comment: There is not. The interface allows the possibility for future expansion, but it isn't implemented that way.